# Получить данные со страницы Sony с помощью PHP, curl

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Хочу получить результат с такой вот страницы:
https://services.sony.co.uk/supportmvc/en/Repair/WarrantyChecker
для примера imei - 358121089225561

Пробуй подключиться через curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://services.sony.co.uk/supportmvc/en/Repair/WarrantyChecker');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"strFormID":"supportForm","strFormName":"warrantyform","lstField":[{"strFieldName":"ModelName","strFieldValue":""},{"strFieldName":"SerialNumber","strFieldValue":""},{"strFieldName":"IMEINumber","strFieldValue":"352876061564677"},{"strFieldName":"ContactReason","strFieldValue":"I need help to use a product"},{"strFieldName":"PhoneCountryCode","strFieldValue":""},{"strFieldName":"EmailSender","strFieldValue":"customersupport.LANG@eu.sony.com"},{"strFieldName":"EmailSenderToClfy","strFieldValue":"customersupport.LANG@eu.sony.com"},{"strFieldName":"EmailReason1","strFieldValue":"Clarify"},{"strFieldName":"EmailReason2","strFieldValue":"WEBFORM"},{"strFieldName":"Clarify","strFieldValue":"yes"},{"strFieldName":"FormTitle","strFieldValue":"Warranty Checker"}]}');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Mobile Safari/537.36';
    $headers[] = 'accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01';
    $headers[] = 'content-length: 766';
    $headers[] = 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br';
    $headers[] = 'content-type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'content-length: 766';
    $headers[] = 'origin: https://services.sony.co.uk';
    $headers[] = 'referer: https://services.sony.co.uk/supportmvc/en/Repair/WarrantyCheckerConfirm';
    $headers[] = 'cookie: _abck=592A9BCEC6046328A59B419F07012427~-1~YAAQz6DVFzMeuRp2AQAAqkWiQwXE+nIzBGOAjx/6rjlLvF4Ld3+WlaJW9p2MlMUfjg8wcE9Uh+jgmVgq/aNr5FE/F6pM2vd9GPZxsvbIVgNezvZWS3flSUGs1Dz4feeDHwoY+ESEH1orYlYgb6HAxufYmkU9eAKWnetWYCUXubKieCJn4BwOthQFCBfOpK/K4sOy4IXK2yXoYZ1a16cg/cRwPUJqYCgkuWNSnRFdWBRulqrdmtd2HBAIB4u3I510IrFBk/dHBdWHCa5fcDqhJyXV+GgqU12K7TR85APYZpCHJXNIKNV5r946~-1~-1~-1; _hjid=919fd89d-4031-489c-ab9b-d95c00b4689e; _evidon_consent_cookie={"consent_date":"2020-12-08T18:34:39.867Z","categories":{"6":true},"vendors":{"6":{"50":true,"63":true,"66":true,"80":true,"81":true,"82":true,"128":true,"174":true,"242":true,"243":true,"249":true,"257":true,"355":true,"395":true,"467":true,"662":true,"828":true,"1272":true,"1487":true,"2516":true,"2572":true,"2645":true,"2806":true,"3490":true,"3632":true,"6080":true,"6171":true,"6359":true,"6423":true,"6609":true}},"cookies":{"6":true},"consent_type":1}; _ga=GA1.3.1959840170.1607452480; _gid=GA1.3.1673893320.1607452480; ASP.NET_SessionId=4z5pknsspom5z2okkrhu1o2v; bm_sz=E4818D9A87D605DD4E9DCC975828ACE9~YAAQFGReaKjpvj12AQAAd9Q3SApgRLZFgLaKV6RhpET/N7UG9lVprWEj8lssMS4EphQmDEe2VKd0pjDst5TPM2igKMuMeit7NglZCO8/0+BmcPt8VZRLThdXFNUNsFN7Z8ydbWwCPpxXTnd0aL79T4BRpFEhTMmEG4pRX0wcVmmf2oTz507EafbeiGMwSJwH; bannerLoaded=; bannerViewed=; fil_p31=; gpv_p70=; _hjIncludedInPageviewSample=1; _hjTLDTest=1; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; _hjIncludedInSessionSample=1; s_dur=1607529388300; AMCVS_7286403D53B6AA9A0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=1; AMCV_7286403D53B6AA9A0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=1585540135%7CMCIDTS%7C18605%7CMCMID%7C91993739844872673120459084949485821243%7CMCAAMLH-1608134188%7C6%7CMCAAMB-1608134188%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1607536588s%7CNONE%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C4.4.0; s_cc=true; gpv_p7=spt%3Arepair; gpv_p1=; nvl_v29=; ak_bmsc=6188E0DC7D7C23205964D4E220FB54C5685E6414A92F0000ABF3D05F836B641A~plVswfVcinojcE9zPSUSsBsRRBgBQ3O6LVbyp+Xu+apjfESdqTga20SwpFP7uuqBsVL/gMixapmYSHCrzwhvMcCTEOKZT+GXKAuLvVm/gsahV8wctA9K93xmZlcfYqqQ4mdoTWBdMksO3+pVleijFJ8BW70gvBvEW9jwjnXfFDg7v6rZaKnwl2eoMmrKXFONTbt/ofm7FuOWAtqCq8btNoi3xluyjz9r6xTXYp9cdcWjLsdQV/xzxbH46WuQL8Qcg6; AWSALB=fHxYo1UUfWhG2dnLJfcKT7hkx9AjKFszkPaoOSaLuAbRujqalAA34ux0zPgt4PRwU8OG+yLj97aJGyOgx31jVXDcV9xwRLS74FzHA35z65WeeiynKD1qM35qlBLL; AWSALBCORS=fHxYo1UUfWhG2dnLJfcKT7hkx9AjKFszkPaoOSaLuAbRujqalAA34ux0zPgt4PRwU8OG+yLj97aJGyOgx31jVXDcV9xwRLS74FzHA35z65WeeiynKD1qM35qlBLL; bm_sv=8EADCFB86E584C1E120F4B6BFDC91076~si5SjL4O1rejQ4AIs4kSDR778oOAsr/SnG9P07l7iNKWbYYoBD5VZJSKwo6QZjZ3ScdNBeHWoYMEluCUbBgKDICenCg23Gqyenfs4vuiNLoRoaEfj7cZ8WC9MdSNMubIuFsnYU+gNEBDH5bS82qDL2kCziHOYbzSq0QTmD871QA=; utag_main=v_id:017643a245b50024811a9f835ca603073004006b00bd0$_sn:2$_se:26$_ss:0$_st:1607532735470$vapi_domain:sony.co.uk$dc_visit:2$ses_id:1607529387132%3Bexp-session$_pn:13%3Bexp-session$dc_event:13%3Bexp-session$dc_region:eu-west-1%3Bexp-session; _gat_sonygwo=1; gpv_pn=spt%3Arepair%3Awarrantychecker; gpv_v89=https%3A%2F%2Fservices.sony.co.uk%2Fsupportmvc%2Fen%2FRepair%2FWarrantyChecker; s_ips=1181; s_tp=1974; s_ppv=https%253A%2F%2Fservices.sony.co.uk%2Fsupportmvc%2Fen%2FRepair%2FWarrantyChecker%2C75%2C60%2C1482%2C1%2C2; s_nr30=1607530944517-Repeat';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Но в ответ приходит {"redirectUrl":"WarrantyCheckerConfirm"}

Что я не так делаю и как необходимо сделать?
Пробовал POSTFIELD задать через http_build_query, вообще не вернуло данных
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Собственно на сайте тоже самое и происходит, Вам курл вернул ответ сайта, он сообщил что нужно перейти на другую страницу, попробуйте добавить следующее, что бы curl сам переходил дальше: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin вставил после `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);` не сработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = "https://services.sony.co.uk/supportmvc/en/Repair/";

$pth = "WarrantyChecker";

$IMEI = 358121089225561;

$post = '{"strFormID":"supportForm","strFormName":"warrantyform","lstField":[{"strFieldName":"ModelName","strFieldValue":""},{"strFieldName":"SerialNumber","strFieldValue":""},{"strFieldName":"IMEINumber","strFieldValue":"'.$IMEI.'"},{"strFieldName":"ContactReason","strFieldValue":"I need help to use a product"},{"strFieldName":"PhoneCountryCode","strFieldValue":""},{"strFieldName":"EmailSender","strFieldValue":"customersupport.LANG@eu.sony.com"},{"strFieldName":"EmailSenderToClfy","strFieldValue":"customersupport.LANG@eu.sony.com"},{"strFieldName":"EmailReason1","strFieldValue":"Clarify"},{"strFieldName":"EmailReason2","strFieldValue":"WEBFORM"},{"strFieldName":"Clarify","strFieldValue":"yes"},{"strFieldName":"FormTitle","strFieldValue":"Warranty Checker"}]}';

$headers = array('content-type: application/json');

$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . $pth);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);


    $pth = $result['redirectUrl'];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . $pth);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    preg_match("/section id=\"Contact\".*?<h3><h3>(.*?)<\/h3>/is", $result, $matches);

    print $matches[1];
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь!)